# login with python requests (mangadex.cc)

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and I am trying to make a web scraper for a website called mangadex, I am trying to get a login function working but I can't seem to get the request part down. Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

The search page is protected by the login page.

Here's my code:

```
import requests


def login(username: str, password: str):
    url = "https://mangadex.cc/login/ajax/actions.ajax.php?function=login&nojs=1"
    with requests.session() as session:
        payload = {
            "login_username": username,
            "login_password": password
        }
        session.post(url, data=payload)
        return session


def search(session, title):
    resp = session.get("https://mangadex.cc/search", params={"title": title})
    return resp.text


session = login("VALIDUSERNAME", "VALIDPASSWORD")
search(session, "foo")
```

the website: https://mangadex.cc/

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What's the problem?

Comment: I've never used the session feature of `requests`, but I would think that the session is probably destroyed once you leave the `with` block. In your `login` function you should probably create a session object using `session = requests.session()`, connect by posting and return the session object. Alternatively you could have both `login` and `search` take a session object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, the login url is wrong.

**NO:**
`https://mangadex.cc/login/ajax/actions.ajax.php?function=login&nojs=1`

**YES**:
`https://mangadex.cc/ajax/actions.ajax.php?function=login`

---

**Second**, the AJAX-Request requires a specific header.

```
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

If you send an AJAX request without `x-requested-with` header, it will respond that you have attempted a hack.

```
Hacking attempt... Go away.
```

**Third**, don't close the session.

**Code:**

```py
def login(username: str, password: str):
    url = "https://mangadex.cc/ajax/actions.ajax.php?function=login"
    header = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    payload = {
        "login_username": username,
        "login_password": password,
    }

    session = requests.session()
    req = session.post(url, headers=header, data=payload)
    return session
```

Comment: question how would I know that I need to add a header? Is it an ajax specific header or like it can found through inspecting the webpage? thank you so much for the help